# Value of combo box selected not adding to the viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

I am using MVC with kendo. A popup dialog opens on the click of the add button of the kendo grid.  The modal dialog contains a fields including two comboboxes. I am populating the Viewmodel when the user enters values in those fields and clicks the add button. I am populating the combo boxes using the GetLanguages() and GetCountries() action methods. So these two comboxes are not populated using the viewmodel. I have set the model field of my viewmodel in the view.  For e.g

```
@using System.Collections
@model CC.GRP.MCRequest.ViewModels.UserProfileViewModel
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.DefaultLanguageCode)
```

Selecting the comboboxes doesnt add the value to the viewmodel. Could someone let me know if I am doing something wrong. Do I need to add the listcollection of countries in my view model and populate the collections in my viewmodel within the controller before sending it to the view. If that is the case how do i do it. Below is my code

```
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Forename)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Forename)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PreferredName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PreferredName)
        </div>

      <div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.DefaultLanguageCode)
     //   .Name("LanguageCode")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
        .DataTextField("LanguageName")
        .DataValueField("DefaultLanguageCode")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetLanguages", "Admin").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
        )
    )
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DefaultCountryCode)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.DefaultCountryCode)
     //   .Name("CountryCode")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
        .DataTextField("Country")
        .DataValueField("DefaultCountryCode")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetCountries", "Admin").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
        )
    )
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TimeZoneName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.TimeZoneName)
     //   .Name("TimeZoneID")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
        .DataTextField("TimeZoneName")
        .DataValueField("TimeZoneID")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetTimeZones", "Admin").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
        )
    )
</div>
```

UserProfile_Read populates the viewmodel

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult GetLanguages()
        {
            return Json(MCRHelper.GetLanguages(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult GetCountries()
        {
            return Json(MCRHelper.GetCountries(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult UserProfile_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var users = mcrRepository.GetUserProfileById(0).AsQueryable().ProjectTo<UserProfileViewModel>();
            var response = users.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }



 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UserProfile_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, UserProfileViewModel userVM)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (userVM.UserProfileID == 0)
            {
                mcrRepository.CreateUserProfile(Mapper.Map<UserProfile>(userVM));
                return Json(mcrRepository.GetTeams().ToDataSourceResult(request));
            }
            else
            {
                mcrRepository.UpdateUserProfile(Mapper.Map<UserProfile>(userVM));
            }
            return null;


        }
```

**Repository**

```
public void CreateUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile)
        {
            if (MCRHelper.UserValidate() == 1)
            {
                var userProfiles = db.spInsertUserProfile(userProfile.EmployeeID,
                                                          userProfile.Forename,
                                                          userProfile.Surname,
                                                          userProfile.PreferredName, 
                                                          userProfile.DefaultLanguageCode,
                                                          userProfile.DefaultCountryCode, 
                                                          userProfile.TimeZoneID, 
                                                          userProfile.Domain, 
                                                          userProfile.NetworkID, 
                                                          userProfile.EmailAddress, 
                                                          true,
                                                          MCRHelper.GetShortname());
            }
        }
```

**Screen**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to add breakpoints and stepping through the code to see how far you are getting? Are your controller methods working?

Comment: The get action methods all work fine. The combo boxes get populated when the add dialog box opens. Its only while saving an exception occurs, I get null exception error saying languages and country fields are null

Comment: A-Ha! can you please post your save action and the exception message

Comment: I have updated my post action. The error message is that language and country is null

Comment: I have added the repository method too in the post

Comment: If you put a break point  at  CreateUserProfile method Are the rest of the fields populated with the correct updated values?

Comment: Yes. The other fields in the view model get populated

Comment: I have updated the post with the screen shot of the grid. As you can see the default country code and language doesnt get added to the grid like the other fields. There seems to be some issue with my drop down mapping

Comment: Try Emmanuel solution. That is what is recommended by Telerik.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the name you put on the combobox it may prevent *DefaultLanguageCode* to be correctly mapped to the viewModel attribute, Because you called you combobox *LanguageDD*.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.DefaultLanguageCode)
        //.Name("LanguageDD") <-- here
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
        .DataTextField("LanguageName")
        .DataValueField("LanguageCode")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetLanguages", "Admin").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
        )
    )
```

Comment: Good Catch! that is the Telerik recommended fix.

Comment: I have done as you have recommended and it adds to the grid however what adds is the code. I need the value of the combobox to be displayed. I have updated the post

Comment: .DataValueField("LanguageName")

Comment: @Tom can you show use your Grid declaration ? if you bind your column to DefaultLanguageCode, are you using a simple `column.bound(m=>m.DefaultLanguageCode)` or `column.ForeignKey("DefaultLanguageCode", LanguagesInASelectList)`